# Fetching place from location

Tags: javascript, dart, google-places-api, google-geocoding-api

If i have the longitude and latitude of a location i can use reverse `geocoding` to get basic information about a location (Like the address), but i want more information. I'm using the Places API for a search-bar, and that returns a huge amount of data, but i can't get a place from a Latitude and longitude.

I've found that the `places API` supports `place details`, but for that i need a reference which i can't get from anywhere.

Note: I'm writing this in dart, but the dart api is just a wrapper around javascript, which is why i tagged this as both.

Comment: can you get a Place from an address? if so, then get the address from the lat/lon first...

Comment: I've thought about that, but it seems inefficient. There has to be a better way.

Comment: hmm. i can see that your screen name is apropos...

Answer (score 1):

The [PlaceResult](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#PlaceResult) object contains an `reference` attribute that should be used in `PlaceDetailsRequest` provided to `PlacesService.getDetails`.

Comment: I don't have a PlaceResult to begin with, i just have the LatLng object.

Comment: You first need to perform a `nearbySearch` or `radarSearch` with `PlaceService`.

Comment: Can i count on the reference being static for a place?

Comment: I think the reference is always the same by seeing [the Place details example](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/place-details).

Comment: Just checked the documentation, I must have missed it the first time. References aren't guaranteed to be the same for the same place, but the same reference should always return the same place. It's a one way guarantee.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up going with the `PlaceService.textSearch` route. This was not nearly as dirty as i expected. The function i ended up with looks like this:

```
void placeFromLocation(LatLng location, void callback(PlaceResult)) {
    GeocoderRequest geocoderRequest = new GeocoderRequest()
        ..location = location;
    geocoder.geocode(geocoderRequest, (List<GeocoderResult> results, GeocoderStatus status) {
        if(status == GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            TextSearchRequest request = new TextSearchRequest()
                ..query = results[0].formattedAddress
                ..location = results[0].geometry.location
                ..radius = 40;
            placeService.textSearch(request, (List<PlaceResult> results, PlacesServiceStatus status) {
                if(status == PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
                    callback(results[0]);
                }else{
                    print("Not place found");
                }
            });
        }else{
            print("Error geocoding address");
        }
    });
}
```